# sequence diagram for typical webrtc use cases (like text, video, audio )

Tags: webrtc, sequence-diagram

I hope my question is legit... I am asking this question because after 1 week reading many blogs, playing with many sample apps, and the official API, I am still very confused, and where to start the coding...

Overall, in term of system architecture between browers <-> web servers <-> Signaling servers, etc.. I got it clearly since there are tons of diagrams out there. But I cannot get myself confidence with the coding, all those classes and methods and events... such as **RTCPeerConnection Interface** , **RTCDataChannel**,  **signalingState** , etc...

A sequence diagram for "Alice text/video call Bob" would be very helpful for the coding. If N/A I will make one myself and share in answer section

Comment: Your question is legit and I don't know why it got downvoted. WebRTC has a rather complicated workflow and I'm not aware of such a diagram which will be helpful for newbies.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/

See the section: 10.4 Call Flow Browser to Browser

It is a complete workflow diagram, including all the webRTC internals topics, like PeerConnections, media description, offer, answers, etc.

Comment: It is actually VERY close to what I wanted... I need something even deeper than that, at JS api call level (maybe I am asking too much). +1 for you

Answer (score 2):

This slide might help:
http://www.slideshare.net/alexpiwi5/overviewpeerconnectionlifetime

you have on each side of the central row the sequence of the JS API you need to call.

Comment: Your diagram is still high level architecture, but I like it. voted up